# Is it possible to delete/remove a wx.aui.AuiManager pane?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to remove a pane from the wx.aui.AuiManager.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this might work:

```
manager.DetachPane(pane)
pane.Destroy()
manager.Update()
```

Comment: almost :P

I've discovered the DestroyOnClose flag so when we hide the pane, it's destroyed.

Comment: "pane" must be a PaneInfo but a Window-derived class. If not, Destroy() won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing segfaults due to stale (deleted) panels left in an AuiManager; I cleared them with the following:

```
nbpanes = manager.GetAllPanes()
for pane in nbpanes:
    pane.DestroyOnClose()
    manager.ClosePane(pane)
```

`nbpanes` is a list of PaneInfo objects

Answer (score 0):

```
panel_list = []

manager.AddPane(panel1,....)
panel_list.append(panel1)

manager.AddPane(panel2,....)
panel_list.append(panel2)
#and so on..
```

Creating a list and append the things (place of **manager**s) to it will make it easy, I think.Then;

Instead **Destroy**, `ShowPane(i, False)` is reasonable for reusing. And don't forget the `Update()`:

```
for i in panel_list:
    manager.ShowPane(i, False)
    manager.Update()
```